# Detect elements with attribute without value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Lets say I've got

```
<div class="some-class" selected></div>
```

I'm trying to say if it has attr 'selected', but

```
$(".some-class").attr("selected") //undefined
$(".some-class").is("*[selected]") // false
```

Am I able to say if it has `selected` attrbute even if it has no value?

Comment: that's not valid markup

Comment: @billyonecan why are you saying that this is an invalid markup..? What if user need to set some unique identity to that element by means of that attibute..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy because a `div` doesn't have a `selected` attribute

Comment: @billyonecan Yeah that's right, div does not have to do anything with that attribute.. but it might be useful for implementing some other logics right..?  :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy in that case you'd use `data-` attributes, or you could just use a class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [`has attribute selector`](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) at this context,

```
$(".some-class").is("[selected]")
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W3dc8/)

Comment: `is()` returns a boolean (true/false), `.some-class[selected]` would return the element itself

Comment: @dandavis then we have to extract its length property.. like `if($('.some-class[selected]').length)`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I didn't downvote. This answer is correct, although the markup in the question is invalid

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
$(".some-class[selected]")
```

then check for existence

```
let element = $(".some-class[selected]");
if (element.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Write a function `hasAttr()` which checks if provided attribute it `undefined` or not. If it is `undefined` means attribute does not exist.

```
$.fn.hasAttr = function(name) {  
   return this.attr(name) !== undefined;
};

 if($('.some-class').hasAttr('selected'))
{
  //do your stuff 
}
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors if you would add some explanations for your intention.